# Reading from a file diagonally and having the diagonal characters create a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to read a file containing information on different lines - for example the file may contain

```
12345678910
abcdefghij
zyxwvutsrq
```

I will then need to read the code diagonally so my list would be:

```
(1bx)(2cw)(3dv)
```

I have tried using zip and just can't figure out a way to get it to work.

EDIT

Is there anyway to also make it take into account the diagonals before the top left corner for example:

```
(ay)(z)
```

in the example file I used.

Edit 2: this is my almost complete code

```
with open(FileName) as diagonal :
    a = diagonal.read().splitlines()
    l = [a[i][i:] for i in range(len(a))]
    Diaglist = [''.join(i) for i in zip(*l)]

with open(FileName) as diagonal1 :
    b = diagonal1.read().splitlines()
    o = [b[i][:i] for i in range(len(b))]
    Diaglist1 = [''.join(i) for i in zip(*o)]
```

When I run the file I get the correct diagonals for the first with so from the top right to left but the second with so from the top right downwards I just get an empty list.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Loop. Move from top of the list. So top line `x` is the first character, then take `x + 1` for the middle line character. Ending with the last row, `x + 2`

Comment: Can your lines be of differing lengths (yours are), and what happens at the end, do the diagonals wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
>>> with open('file') as f:
...     l = f.read().splitlines()
>>> l
['12345678910', 'abcdefghij', 'zyxwvutsrq']

>>> l = [l[0]] + [l[1][1:]] + [l[2][2:]]  # remove 'a' from `l[1]` and `zy` from `l[2]`
>>> l
['12345678910', 'bcdefghij', 'xwvutsrq']

>>> list(zip(*l))  # zip them
[('1', 'b', 'x'), ('2', 'c', 'w'), ('3', 'd', 'v'), ('4', 'e', 'u'), ('5', 'f', 't'), ('6', 'g', 's'), ('7', 'h', 'r'), ('8', 'i', 'q')]

>>> [''.join(i) for i in list(zip(*l))]  # also join them
['1bx', '2cw', '3dv', '4eu', '5ft', '6gs', '7hr', '8iq']
>>>
```

---

If you don't know how many lines in your file, we can use some [magic](/questions/tagged/magic) code like `[a[i][i:] for i in range(len(a))]`.

Try:

```
with open('file') as f:
    a = f.read().splitlines()

l = [a[i][i:] for i in range(len(a))]
final_list = [''.join(i) for i in zip(*l)]

print(final_list)
```

---

As your edit, you can change `a[i][i:]` to `a[i][:i]`. Very simple:

```
with open('file') as f:
    a = f.read().splitlines()

l = [a[i][:i] for i in range(len(a))]
final_list = [''.join(i) for i in zip(*l)][1:]  # since the first element in the list will be empty (`''`), remove it. 

print(final_list)
```

Comment: The file can contain any number of rows/columns and can have any length. I tried to use the code you have typed with the actual file that I have and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: That works amazingly man, thank you. Is here anyway to make it so it also checks the diagonals in the opposite way...I will edit my main post

Comment: You're an absolute legend mate, thank you soo much. I've been stuck on this for hours now.

Comment: @T.Lowe: No problem. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) to understand how did I do that. Also remember accept this answer if it's helpful :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you anymore but can you please take a look at my last edit.

Comment: @T.Lowe: Ah, I understand what's the problem now. Give me some time since I'm eating breakfast ;)

Comment: @T.Lowe: Well, so now you're trying to zip `(ay)(z)`, what's the expect output?

Comment: The expected output is one list that contains the diagonals for the entire file.

Comment: Ah, I understand what the problem is. Because `zip()` only zip the list **5 times** if the smallest length element in that list is 5 like `'utsrq'` in the `['12345678910', 'bcdefghij', 'xwvutsrq', 'wvutsrq', 'vutsrq', 'utsrq']`.  However in your example, maybe you just want to **reverse** the first list like `Diaglist[::-1]` gives you?

Answer (score 0):

The following will work for an arbitrary number of lines *of the same length*, and *wraps the final diagonals*.  This may not be what you want.

```
def diagonals(lines):
    size = len(lines[0])
    positions = [[(i + x) % size for x in range(len(lines))] 
                 for i in range(size)]
    return ["".join([lines[i][p] for i, p in enumerate(posn)]) 
            for posn in positions]

>>> print(diagonals(['1234567891', 'abcdefghij', 'zyxwvutsrq']))
['1bx', '2cw', '3dv', '4eu', '5ft', '6gs', '7hr', '8iq', '9jz', '1ay']
```